# Nextjs Enriching AWS AuthUser Data with Data From MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, react-context

I have a NextJS application which is using AWS Amplify Auth to login users. Due to the limitations of AWS Cognito custom user attributes, I am storing extra user data in a users collection in MongoDB. I am using the AWS Cognito user sub as the user ID in MongoDB and have a Lambda call in a function that is called during my _app.js render. The function is working correctly and I am able to combine the AWS Cognito user data and MongoDB data into a UserContext which is available across my app. The issue I'm having is that the function in _app.js to get and combine the two sets of user data is not completing before my pages render, resulting in an error from the page (which disappears when the page is reloaded).

Is there a best practise on how to ensure the _app.js function is completed and the context populated before the pages are rendered?

Here is the relevant snippet from my _app,js file:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const getUserData = async () => {
    const userProfileData = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
    if (userProfileData !== null) {
      try {
        const userData = await axios.get(
          "https://example-aws-endpoint/?docId=" +
            userProfileData.attributes.sub
        );
        setUserProfile({ ...userData.data[0], ...userProfileData });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, [userProfile]);
  return (
    <Authenticator hideSignUp={true} components={components}>
      <UserContext.Provider value={userProfile}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Layout signOut={Auth.signOut}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Here is my UserContext file:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

In my index.js page, I am trying to set an initial state from the UserContext:

```
export default function Home() {
const user = useContext(UserContext);
const [userOrgs, setUserOrgs] = useState(user.userOrgs)
```

When this index.js page loads, the UserContext is still undefined as the _app.js function hasn't completed which is causing an error setting the state of setUserOrgs.

What is the best/correct way to overcome this?